# Why DWebBrowserEvents2::NewProcess() receives pWB2==NULL in second parameter

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation, bho

This dispatch is also known as `DISPID_NEWPROCESS`.

If you start a new `IWebBrowser2` with `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer)`, then it will by default start in Protected Mode (you can see it in Internet Options | Security | Internet | Enable Protected Mode). However, if you then `Navigate()` to an URL that is in your "Trusted sites" list, then it will need to open without Protected Mode. Then IE will silently create a new process, invalidate old `IWebBrowser2` and create a new `IWebBrowser2`. Then your `IWebBrowser2` becomes useless, which is certainly a problem.

However, IE is supposed to fire `DISPID_NEWPROCESS` event, which should have the `IDispatch*` for new process in its second parameter.

The problem is that the `pWB2` parameter will contain `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged IE, and found out that the parameter will have `NULL` if your ProtectedMode (low integrity) `IWebBrowser2` is becoming non-ProtectedMode (medium integrity) `IWebBrowser2`.

**Details:**

The interesting code is located in `IEFRAME!CIEFrameAuto::_HandleProtectedModeRedirect()`. It will call `IEFRAME!IsProtectedModeProcess()` and based on its results will eventually call either `FireEvent_NewProcess()` with `pWB2` parameter explicitly set to NULL, or `FireEvent_NewProcess()` with `pWB2` parameter containing good value.

I believe the reason is security. Otherwise you could start a low integrity `IWebBrowser2` from a low integrity application, then navigate to a trusted URL, and get hold on a medium-integrity `IWebBrowser2`, which is basically a privilege escalation.